# Build and deploy only updated/changed files - Hudson

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I am using hudson for continuous integration to build the project and deploy it to server which is happening but hudson have to build only the changed files committed in the svn and deploy/patch them in the server. Is there any way to accomplish?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12939663/734687, maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer completely without a better understand of how your server and codebase are set up. However, there are some ways you can do this. If you have the server broken into components, i.e. chat service, web page, video, etc, you can break each into its own folder your SVN trunk. Then you can give each a separate project, with a distinct SVN hook for each.

The other possibility, if you are building inside of Hudson's workspace for your project (using SVN integration) is to do an SVN update ONLY and not clean the workspace. You can then deploy only the files that have a modified timestamp later than the time the build was triggered. This will only build modified projects and only deploy those. You still should have a 'clean' build occurring somewhere, though, to ensure that lingering build artifacts aren't causing or hiding bugs.