# How to get the list of changed file in SVN from Jenkins

Tags: svn, groovy, jenkins

[Process only changed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931786/process-only-changed-files/12939663#12939663)

Using SVN with Jenkins, I need to pass the list of changed files to some other process. Using the code from the above link, I get a result like this: Script returned: [hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet$Path@6e78d3d7]

I am not familiar with Groovy. Can somebody help me out? Thanks.

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.util.*
import hudson.scm.*
import hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet.LogEntry

// work with current build
def build = Thread.currentThread()?.executable

// for testing, use last build or specific build number
//def item = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("Update_SRC_Branch") 
//def build = item.getLastBuild()   
//def build = item.getBuildByNumber(35)   

// get ChangesSets with all changed items
def changeSet= build.getChangeSet()
List<LogEntry> items = changeSet.getItems()

def affectedFiles = items.collect { it.paths }
def fileNames = affectedFiles.flatten()

new File("/tmp/svn.change.list").withWriter { out ->
    fileNames.each {
      out.println it
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That means you have a list of [these](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/scm/SubversionChangeLogSet.Path.html)

Try

```
fileNames.each {
  out.println it.path
}
```

Comment: Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BuildTomcatLinux
Updating https://cmtoldsvnapp01.dev.bmocm.com/stuff/Tomcat/trunk/apache-tomcat-7.0.42-src
U         readme.txt
At revision 26
Script returned: [hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet$Path@186db2c7]
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: It works. The output to the file is right, but display in Jenkins not, as above shown. [root@cmtoldsvnapp01 tmp]# more svn.change.list
/Tomcat/trunk/apache-tomcat-7.0.42-src/readme.txt

Answer (score 0):

Use currentExecutable instead of executable for Build Flows.